# hide command usage argument on browser of shell_exec PHP in windows

Tags: php, shell-exec, traceroute

I make the traceroute web based. I use shell_exec to execute the process and show the output via browser. I have problem with the first I call the page on browser. There is usage of tracert command show. I try to hide it by place the script inside the function. yes, it works but another element like map when I start load the page doesn't show. Here is my php code :

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<body>
<?
$host  = @$_POST['host']; 
$trace = @$_POST['trace'];
$self  = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
?>
...
        <form name="tools" action="<?php $self ?>" method="post">
    <p><font size="2">Your IP is <?php $ip ?> </font></p>
    <input type="text" name="host" value=""></input>
    <input type="submit" name="trace" value="Traceroute!"></input>
    </form>
    <?php
    if ($_POST['submit']) 
{
    if (($host == 'Enter Host or IP') || ($host == "")) {
        echo '<br><br>You must enter a valid Host or IP address.';
        exit; } 

    if(eregi("^[a-z]",  $host))
    {
        $host_name = $host;
        $host_ip = gethostbyname($host);
    }
    else
    {
        $host_name = gethostbyaddr($host);
        $host_ip = $host;
    } 
}
    $host= preg_replace ("[-a-z0-9!#$%&\'*+/=?^_`{|}~]","",$host);
    $command = "tracert $host";
    $fp = shell_exec("$command 2>&1");
    $output .= (htmlentities(trim($fp)));
    echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
    echo '<br/>'; 
?>
...

</body>
</html>
```

And the html code (browser output) :

```
'''
<form name="tools" action="" method="post">

    <p><font size="2">Your IP is  </font></p>

    <input type="text" name="host" value=""></input>

    <input type="submit" name="trace" value="Traceroute!"></input>

    </form>

    <pre>Usage: tracert [-d] [-h maximum_hops] [-j host-list] [-w timeout] 
               [-R] [-S srcaddr] [-4] [-6] target_name

Options:
    -d                 Do not resolve addresses to hostnames.
    -h maximum_hops    Maximum number of hops to search for target.
    -j host-list       Loose source route along host-list (IPv4-only).
    -w timeout         Wait timeout milliseconds for each reply.
    -R                 Trace round-trip path (IPv6-only).
    -S srcaddr         Source address to use (IPv6-only).
    -4                 Force using IPv4.
    -6                 Force using IPv6.</pre><br/> <script type="text/javascript">

    var pinImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage ("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_xpin_letter_withshadow&chld=pin_star|%E2%80%A2|CC3300|000000|FF9900",

        new google.maps.Size (70, 83),

        new google.maps.Point (0,0),

        new google.maps.Point (10,34));

    var pinShadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage ("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_shadow",

        new google.maps.Size (89, 85),

        new google.maps.Point (0, 0),

        new google.maps.Point (12, 35));



    function initialize() {

    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(38.822591, 150.46875);

    var myOptions = {

    zoom: 2,

    center: myLatlng,

    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,

    }

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
        }
...
```

All I need is to hide the help usage of traceroute like in my html code. So when I first load the page, it just show the text field, button and map without that usage of tracert.
I really need your help as soon as possible. Big thanks.

Comment: .....Ever heard of Javascript?

Comment: @dynamic: what specifically are you thinking of?

Comment: Yes, I've used it too. And why or what I have to do?

Comment: Well, he wants to hide the `<pre>Usage: tracert [-d] [-h maximum_hops] [-j host-list] [-w timeout]`..and so on, correct? Just use `getelementbyid("id of <pre> here").style.display = "block";`, and set the default value to `none`. Or am I completely misunderstanding the question?

Comment: well, you're redirecting stderr to stdout, if you drop the `2>&1` that will stop. But you're getting the error message because you're passing a bad (or no) `$host` to tracert.

Comment: Yes @dynamic, That is what I mean. Is it handle with Javascript?? Not with PHP?? where I have to place the code like what you suggest?? Thank You.

Comment: Okay, so do I have to delete 2>&1 ??

Answer (score 1):

Consider what these two lines do:

```
$host= preg_replace ("[-a-z0-9!#$%&\'*+/=?^_`{|}~]","",$host);
$command = "tracert $host";
```

You may find it instructive to print the value of `$host` immediately before running your command. You've stripped out all numbers and letters from your hostname -- what exactly do you intend to look up?

I can appreciate that you're aggressively stripping the input to try to avoid a [shell command injection vulnerability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection#Shell_injection).

Instead of *stripping* characters you should instead *keep* specific characters. Keep only `[a-z0-9:.-]`. (I don't know the best way to express this in PHP. Within the brackets the `.` means only `.`. Keep that meaning in whatever tool you use.) (The `:` is for IPv6 hosts with numeric names. Feel free to ditch it if you don't want to allow IPv6.)

Comment: Hey, @Sarnold, thanks for your suggest. but would you mind to explain it clearer because i'm newbie and a little hard to understand. If i keep only [a-z0-9:.] the host like www.poltek-malang.ac.id cannot be proceed because of the (-). So from your suggest I've mistake in those two lines?? how to fix it but in your easy explanation. I'm sorry for too annoying of my question. Thank You.

Comment: How about stripping all single quote character `'` and quoting everything between a pair of single quotes? Won't it prevent any form of injection?

Comment: @nhahtdh: I wouldn't trust it very far; nothing beats limiting input to known good characters.

Comment: @chumyee: my mistake -- yes, you can add the `-` as well, just make sure it is the first or last character of your character class.

Comment: @sarnold, sorry, what do you mean with the first or the last character of my character class? Sorry for asking anymore. Thank You.

Comment: The `[abc]` syntax in regular expressions introduces a character class; if you put a hyphen in, it'll express a range: `[a-f]`, for example, is `[abcdef]`. If you put the hyphen at the start or end, it turns into just a hyphen.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of shell_exec, use exec. You can supply the command, a variable to receive the output, and a variable to receive the status instead of catching it all in the return of exec.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Also, please use escapeshellcmd and escapeshellarg for sanitizing your commands, http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellcmd.php.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the suggest. so if I use one of two ways above, the usage command won't show when i first load the page in browser, will I? Correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks.

Comment: I've tried them. Yes, it works but the map doesn't show. Any other way I could try?? Please Help. Thank You ...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the actual question, you just don't want to run and output your command when there is no input. You already have

```
if ($_POST['submit']) 
{
```

Just move its closing `}` down past that code:

```
       $host_ip = $host;
    } 
// removed from here
    $host= preg_replace ("[-a-z0-9!#$%&\'*+/=?^_`{|}~]","",$host);
    $command = "tracert $host";
    $fp = shell_exec("$command 2>&1");
    $output .= (htmlentities(trim($fp)));
    echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
    echo '<br/>'; 
} //added here
```

That seems cleaner to me than using JS, but the JS is easy enough too. Just google for "js hide / unhide"