# Get list of traceroute hops with php

Tags: php, traceroute

`shell_exec("traceroute IPaddress)` returns `traceroute to IPaddress (IPaddress), 30 hops max, 40 byte packets`

How do I retrieve the actual list of hops so I can tell where a problem occurs?

Comment: Check http://www.adayinthelifeof.nl/2010/07/30/creating-a-traceroute-program-in-php/ or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10965891/hide-command-usage-argument-on-browser-of-shell-exec-php-in-windows

Comment: I can't get this to work - ignorance of how to construct the command with the parameters in it is probably the cause!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those messages are supposed to be written to `stderr` instead of the regular `stdout`, so I'm not too sure why you're seeing them appear in the output.

Instead of `shell_exec()` I would recommend using `exec()` because it captures both the output AND the return code of the process:

```
exec('traceroute example.com 2>&1', $out, $code);
if ($code) {
    die("An error occurred while trying to traceroute: " . join("\n", $out);
}
print_r($out);
```

To speed up the command a little you could use the `-n` option when you run `traceroute` to avoid having to do DNS lookups for the intermediate hops.

Note that running `traceroute` can take a while; if you run it on the command line you can sometimes see lines with `* * *` in them, which can take ages!

Comment: This also returns `Array ( [0] => traceroute to 88.97.30.31 (88.97.30.31), 30 hops max, 40 byte packets )` - what defines the variable $code?

Comment: @NickIredale Then your `traceroute` is messed up, it should print that message on `stderr`; `$code` gives the return value of the command; `0` means no errors, anything else means something went wrong.

Comment: ah!  printing $code gives 1 not 0, so as you say it isn't working.  If it was, then the command should give the list of hops, should it?

Comment: To print the errors you could do `exec('traceroute example.com 2>&1', $out, $code)`.

Comment: Thanks, you've been really helpful :)  It now returns `Array ( [0] => traceroute to example.com (192.0.43.10), 30 hops max, 40 byte packets [1] => send: Operation not permitted ) 1` so the server must be set up to prevent this - I'll contact my host and see what can be done if anything

Comment: For security reasons shell access is not permitted on my server - oh well, worth a try.

Comment: @Jack Can you explain what "2>&1" means? I tried with and without it and got different results. I would like to know what it means and which one I could rely most on. At least give me a link where to read about it I have tried to google with no success.

Comment: I have read some what it means, according to them it's only get the errors?  I don't see why I get different results then. I can send you my results in private if you want to take a look at them.

Answer (score 0):

Use exec and look at its second parameter :

```
string exec ( string $command [, array &$output [, int &$return_var ]] )
```

Example :

```
<?php

exec('traceroute test.com -m 2', $output);
var_dump($output);
```

Comment: Thanks, just tried that but the result is effectively the same as the original code - the array contains just the one variable - `array(1) { [0]=> string(69) "traceroute to 88.97.30.31 (88.97.30.31), 30 hops max, 40 byte packets" }`, which is the summary of the traceroute rather than the list of hops

Comment: see the edited message, m parameter means number of hops .. "traceroute --help" for more details

Comment: edited version still returns the same - `array(1) { [0]=> string(68) "traceroute to 88.97.30.31 (88.97.30.31), 2 hops max, 40 byte packets" }`

Comment: for me it returns the right output ... 

    array (size=3)
    0 => string 'traceroute to test.com (174.36.85.72), 2 hops max, 60 byte packets' (length=66)
    1 => string ' 1  * * *' (length=9)
    2 => string ' 2  * * *' (length=9)

Comment: The server doesn't permit it, that's why it won't work.  Thanks for your help