# How to get ISP by PHP?

Tags: php, ip

How to get ISP from IP by PHP? For example, how to get string "Zappie Host LLC" from IP http://www.ip2location.com/demo/185.121.170.242

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What you're either looking for is either an `API`, or a `web scraper` which you would build yourself. In order for us to help you better, please update your question so that it tells us which approach you're using, and shows all relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also be sure to let us know what you have tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the [help article](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) regarding how to ask good questions.

Answer (score 0):

If you have proper permission you can use php's exec() to run traceroute that will give you all the 'hops' in this format:

MY isp in the 4th hop.

> CRON01-C11.asr01.mtl1080.fibrenoire.ca (173.231.103.209)

and google in the end (12th hop) since i made a  traceroute for google public dns 8.8.8.8

> google-public-dns-a.google.com (8.8.8.8)  43.820 ms  31.992 ms  74.833
>   ms

Full explaination can be found here on SO:
[Get list of traceroute hops with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13701842/get-list-of-traceroute-hops-with-php)
See comment about looping the 'hops' and store your result in php array.

this might ot give you exacly what your looking for but it can be a simple solution to your 'problem'

---

EDIT: 
use linux's whois instead and call it with exec() from php. it will give you all you want:

```
[llt@lltHomeBox ~]$ whois 185.121.170.242
[Querying whois.ripe.net]
[whois.ripe.net]
% This is the RIPE Database query service.
% The objects are in RPSL format.
%
% The RIPE Database is subject to Terms and Conditions.
% See http://www.ripe.net/db/support/db-terms-conditions.pdf

% Note: this output has been filtered.
%       To receive output for a database update, use the "-B" flag.

% Information related to '185.121.170.0 - 185.121.170.255'

% Abuse contact for '185.121.170.0 - 185.121.170.255' is 'abuse@zappiehost.com'

inetnum:        185.121.170.0 - 185.121.170.255
netname:        GESTION-DBI-NET
descr:          Gestion DBI
country:        NL
admin-c:        GDA107
tech-c:         VA31968-RIPE
status:         SUB-ALLOCATED PA
geoloc:         52.396348 4.851082
mnt-lower:      GestionDBI
mnt-routes:     GestionDBI
mnt-domains:    GestionDBI
mnt-routes:     MNT-NFORCE
remarks:        !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
remarks:        Abuse repots to: abuse@vmpanel.net
remarks:        Please report all ABUSE here with the following information:
remarks:        - Source and Destination IP and Ports
remarks:        - Accurate Timestamp
remarks:        - Full logs about the issue
remarks:        !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
mnt-by:         ADAMBB-MNT
created:        2015-12-20T04:38:14Z
last-modified:  2015-12-20T04:38:14Z
source:         RIPE

role:           Gestion DBI Administrators
address:        490 Place Donato
address:        St-Lin, QC, CANADA, J5M2K8
nic-hdl:        GDA107
mnt-by:         GestionDBI
created:        2015-12-15T15:41:45Z
last-modified:  2015-12-19T19:41:09Z
source:         RIPE # Filtered
remarks:        !========================================== !
remarks:        Administrative requests only. No ABUSE, TECH inquiries will be answered here.
remarks:        !========================================== !
phone:          +18772044324

role:           VMPanel Tech
address:        490 Place Donato
address:        St-Lin, QC, CANADA, J5M2K8
nic-hdl:        VA31968-RIPE
remarks:        !========================================== !
remarks:        Please report any TECHNICAL issues about Routing, IP, DNS here.
remarks:        For issue with your service, please contact your provider.
remarks:        - We do not answer ABUSE request here.
remarks:        !========================================== !
phone:          +18772044324
mnt-by:         GestionDBI
created:        2015-12-15T15:57:30Z
last-modified:  2015-12-19T19:42:29Z
source:         RIPE # Filtered

% Information related to '185.121.170.0/24AS43350'

route:          185.121.170.0/24
descr:          NFOrce Entertainment BV - 185.121.170.0/24 route
origin:         AS43350
mnt-by:         MNT-NFORCE
created:        2015-12-20T10:55:04Z
last-modified:  2015-12-20T10:55:04Z
source:         RIPE

% This query was served by the RIPE Database Query Service version 1.88 (ANGUS)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try gethostbyaddr:

```
<?php
$hostname = gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

echo $hostname;
?>
```